# Gerrit Web UI: Show change-set's that have a status of "Merge Conflict"

Tags: git-merge, gerrit, merge-conflict-resolution

Is there a way in the Gerrit Web UI to show a list of change-set's that currently have a status of "Merge Conflict"?

Perhaps using a search bar query?

I tried these queries:

- `status:"Merge Conflict"` -> showed all *merged* changes
- `status:Merge Conflict` -> syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the search bar like in the following examples.

To search for all open changes with conflicts:

```
status:open AND NOT is:mergeable
```

To search for all open changes with conflicts excluding draft changes:

```
status:open AND NOT is:mergeable AND NOT is:draft
```

Comment: Thanks, this is _almost_ what I was looking for...this query also seems to include drafts. Would this be better? `status:new AND NOT is:mergeable`. Also, do change-set's in `draft` status not get marked as having a merge conflict even if they do?

Comment: No problem, use: status:open AND NOT is:mergeable AND NOT is:draft

Comment: Great! Please update your answer and I'll mark it complete

Comment: Ok, I keep the first way and added the second one.

Comment: Note: An alternative to using `AND NOT` is to prefix the query predicate with `-`, for example:  `status:open -is:mergeable -is:draft`